# Pandas: error when creating a new column using a function that takes one argument from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

I have the following data frame `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'result' : ['s17h10e7', 's5e3h2S105h90e15', 
                               's17H10e7S5e3H2s105h90e15'],
                   'status' : [102, 117, 205]})

result                      status
s17h10e7                    102
s5e3h2S105h90e15            117
s17H10e7S5e3H2s105h90e15    205
```

I have a function named `get_number_after_code` that reads a string and returns the **SUM** of any digits that immediately follow a user-defined code (e.g. a letter):

```
def get_number_after_code(string_to_read, code):

    code_indices = [i for i, char in enumerate(string_to_read) if char == code]

    joined_numbers = []    
    list_of_int_values = []
   
    for idx in code_indices:
        temp_number = []
        for character in string_to_read[idx + 1: ]:
            if not character.isdigit():
                break
            else:
                temp_number.append(character)

            joined_numbers = ''.join(temp_number)
        list_of_int_values.append(int(joined_numbers))

    return sum(list_of_int_values)
```

Examples:

```
get_number_after_code('s5e3h2s105h90e15', 'h')
>> 92

get_number_after_code('s5e3h2s105h90e15', 's')
>> 105
```

I would like to add a column named `col_NEW` to the `df` dataframe.  This `col_NEW` column would display the output of the `get_number_after_code()` function as it is applied to the row element in the `result` column.  As an example, let's assume we use the code 'h' (but it could be either 's' or 'e').  The output would be:

```
result                        status     col_NEW       
s17h10e7                      102        10
s5e3h2s105h90e15              117        92
s17h10e7s5e3h2s105h807e15     205        819
```

To do this, I'm using:

```
df['col_NEW'] = df.apply(get_number_after_code(df['result'], 'h'), axis=1)
```

I'm getting this not-so-helpful `AssertionError`:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21060/915445793.py in <module>
----> 1 df['col_NEW'] = df.apply(count_tests_new(df['result'], 's'), axis=1)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
   8738             kwargs=kwargs,
   8739         )
-> 8740         return op.apply()
   8741 
   8742     def applymap(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply(self)
    686             return self.apply_raw()
    687 
--> 688         return self.apply_standard()
    689 
    690     def agg(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    810 
    811     def apply_standard(self):
--> 812         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    813 
    814         # wrap results

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    816 
    817     def apply_series_generator(self) -> tuple[ResType, Index]:
--> 818         assert callable(self.f)
    819 
    820         series_gen = self.series_generator

AssertionError:
```

Am I using `.apply()` *syntactically* correctly to add `col_NEW`?  If yes, does anyone know what is causing this `AssertionError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking `get_number_after_code` on each row, yet passing a Series object to it. Since it seems you only need the "result" column, use `apply` on that column instead. Also, you can pass the letter (for example "h") as a positional argument. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['col_NEW'] = df['result'].apply(get_number_after_code, args=('h',))
```

or by its keyword:

```
df['col_NEW'] = df['result'].apply(get_number_after_code, code='h')
```

Output:

```
                     result  status  col_NEW
0                  s17h10e7     102       10
1          s5e3h2S105h90e15     117       92
2  s17H10e7S5e3H2s105h90e15     205       90
```